# Trying to display data between two dates .data is present is DB table still it shows No records Found

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to display data between two dates.
My input is 08/17/2018 and 08/18/2018
Data is present in Gridview but still i am getting error like ,No records Found

Here is my code

```
 myConn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT User_Name , Product_Code , Log_Detail  FROM Product_Detail     
                                    WHERE Log_Detail BETWEEN '" + TextBox1.Text + "' AND '" + TextBox2.Text + "' ", myConn);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        GridView1.DataSource = reader;
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            Lab3.Text = "No Records Found";

        }
        myConn.Close();
```

Comment: Do not concat SQL strings. Use Parameters.

Comment: @Fildor Yes, but that's not the answer to his problem.

Comment: Your query looks fine. Try debugging your code and use `Text Visualizer` to see what query is formed. Copy this query and run it on SQL server and see what result you are getting.

Comment: @Neil That's why it's a *comment*.

Comment: @Kalpesh Have you tried performing that query in SQL Management Studio ? What type is your Log_Detail Column?

Comment: Can you be more specific on the issue? I assume, the `no records found` is the problem? Can you provide a database excerpt on how the data is stored and how it looks?

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal I tried same query in SQL but getting error like " this Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '08/15/2018 6:46:27 AM' to data type int."

Comment: @Korashen praju | Guwahati 6445 08/15/2018 6:46:27 AM
dkc | Chandigarh 5911 08/15/2018 6:59:05 AM
yogeen | Nagpur 5911 08/15/2018 7:48:14 AM
swapnil1 | mumbai 6445 08/15/2018 7:48:59 AM

Comment: You really need to tell use **what type the column Log_Detail is** . What you see is only a string representation. Your needed query will depend on if that col is a string, int, date, or whatever.

Comment: @Fildor Log_Detail column hold the date and Current time in UTC format

Comment: Yes, but in what data type? You can hold that data as "date" , as "int" as string representation ... what is it?

Comment: @Fildor User_Name     varchar(50)  Checked
             Product_Code  varchar(50)  Checked
             Log_Detail       varchar(50) Checked

Comment: Ah, that's unfortunate. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/between-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 I would expect "BETWEEN" to perform lexical comparison then. That's probably not what you want. The columns' data type should be date or at least int, so that BETWEEN actually performs a comparison on the data.

Comment: @Fildor ok, Thank You

Comment: So are you saying that the `Log_Detail` field is stored in a string type column, not a date type column?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe that's because of time value in your `datetime` column, Try this:

```
"SELECT User_Name , Product_Code , Log_Detail  FROM Product_Detail WHERE Log_Detail BETWEEN CONVERT ('" + TextBox1.Text + "', GETDATE()) AND CONVERT ('" + TextBox2.Text + "', GETDATE())"
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify dates in the format YYYY-MM-DD.  The format you specify will be interpreted as either DD-MM-YYYY or MM-DD-YYYY, which until the 12th day of the month are generally interchangable.

```
var from = DateTime.ParseExact(TextBox1.Text, "MM/DD/YYYY"); // Change the format to match your locale
var to = DateTime.ParseExact(TextBox2.Text, "MM/DD/YYYY");

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT User_Name , Product_Code , Log_Detail  FROM Product_Detail     
                                WHERE Log_Detail BETWEEN '" + from.ToString("O") + "' AND '" + to.ToString("O") + "' ", myConn);
```